# I need to join 2 table into one object by jpa using OneToOne annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to join to table into one object by JPA using OneToOne annotation with shared primary key, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm getting error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in:
>   com.maciejg.School02.model.StudentsTeachersEntity.loginAndPassword,
>   referenced property unknown:
>   com.maciejg.School02.model.LoginAndPassword.usersinfo

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usersinfo")
public class StudentsTeachersEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "pesel")
    private String pesel;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "usersinfo", cascade = 
        CascadeType.ALL)
    private LoginAndPassword loginAndPassword;

//getters and setters


@Entity
@Table(name="userandpassword")

public class LoginAndPassword {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long username_id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "user_password")
    private String user_password;

    @Column(name= "grade")
    private String grade;

    @Column(name= "comment")
    private String comment;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @MapsId
    private StudentsTeachersEntity studentsTeachersEntity;

//getters and setters
```

Comment: `usersinfo` is not a valid field in `LoginAndPassword`

Comment: Use annotation `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "studentsTeachersEntity", cascade =  CascadeType.ALL)`  for the loginAndPassword property of StudentsTeachersEntity. You might want to rethink the naming of your classes. StudentsTeachersEntity could be User and LoginAndPassword could be LoginInfo.

Comment: Thank You for help that's exactly what I wanted to achieve.